# typescript compiler api, output files and handle errors

Tags: compilation, typescript

I'm trying to do a slightly different thing than the example on the TypeScript [compiler API wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API):

```
var host = ts.createCompilerHost(options);
var program = ts.createProgram(filenames, options, host);
var checker = ts.createTypeChecker(program, /*produceDiagnostics*/ true);
var result = checker.emitFiles();
```

The question is twofold:

1) how to make `emitFiles` to write to a specific path?

2) how to catch and handle compilation errors?

Answer (score 3):

> how to make emitFiles to write to a specific path

The `emitFiles` doesn't do any actual writing. It returns it as a result and *you* need to write it, so you can write it anywhere.

e.g.

```
output.outputFiles.forEach(o => {
    mkdirp.sync(path.dirname(o.name));
    fs.writeFileSync(o.name, o.text, "utf8");
});
```

> how to catch and handle compilation errors?

Using diagnostics:

```
var allDiagnostics = services.getCompilerOptionsDiagnostics()
    .concat(services.getSyntacticDiagnostics(filePath))
    .concat(services.getSemanticDiagnostics(filePath));
```

Source : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/lib/main/lang/modules/building.ts#L28-L30 don't forget to star ;)

Comment: hey, that's cool! how did you know? are there any docs of the compiler APIs or you just read the sources?

Comment: Sources and experimentation e.g. `mkdirp` was added by someone else. You can see code in this package and the brackets one as a reference for how stuff works

Comment: on a closer look those are `atom-typescript` objects and methods, not typescripts. I can't use those.

Comment: `services` is just the `LanguageService`  documented here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API Not AtomTS specific in any way